# mapping new fields in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Say I have a package with a table that has 20 fields in tbl1. I load them into another database via SSIS. If I add 2 new fields in my tbl1, what is the best way to "refresh" my package so that I can see those two fields in my package, and map them to the destination field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to open the package's solution in BIDS and edit it there, same as when you created it in the first place.

Comment: I understand that, but what is that I have to do in order to map those new fields?

Comment: Edit your source component to include the new fields, edit whatever transformations need to be edited, and then map them in your destination.   If you've tried something and gotten a specific error, you should add that to your question instead of asking an open-ended question that is too broad to answer.